# Installed applications not giving any response

Tags: vlc, sublime-text, atom, pycharm

Currently, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04,
From last two days I'm trying to opening my applications but I'm not getting any response,few thing opening like chrome,firefox, terminal, ubuntu software, text editor(built-in).
But When I'm trying to open my other application like VLC, sublime-text, Pycharm, Atom they are not opening. I tried few thing like restarting my PC, trying to install new package from Ubuntu software but they are still not opening. Can anyone suggest me any solution for this.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried installing through the command line? The Ubuntu store won't tell you if dpkg (the component that handles installations) is busy with something else, such as updating, but running an installation through the command line will with (for example) `sudo apt install vlc`. The store just aborts installations without throwing errors, in my experience.

Comment: @Minty I was actually having all these things pre-installed and using them from few months, but two day ago suddenly they were not opening.

Comment: run a non opening app from  a terminal & see if any message is presented

Comment: At your login screen, did you choose a different environment from the cog wheel icon? Your choice should probably be "Ubuntu".

Comment: I tried it, sublime text was opening by tying 'subl' but now it giving error that subl commant not found@doug

Comment: @heynnema sorry man I didn't understand your point

Comment: At your login screen, enter your name, then about where the password entry box is located, there's a little cog wheel icon, and if you click it, a number of choices appear. What is it set to now? Can you change it to "Ubuntu"?